# Using COUNT() implicitly for making a view over game match data?

Tags: mysql, view

I've not used SQL in quite a while and I'm pretty rusty it seems. I've had to do a project recently and needed to use MySQL on Windows and when looking for solutions to this particular query, I get told that you can use COUNT(*) implicitly somehow, but I can't get it to work right.

What I need is something like:

| PLAYER_ID | MATCHES_WON | MATCHES_LOST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |

I have made a simple SQL fiddle of my database [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9775e/2).

Could someone help me out with this? I'm willing to accept that I might have to make a more involved solution with some `CURSOR` and `LOOP` but thought I'd ask here. It's my first question on this community, so sorry if I didn't format this right or it wasn't an appropriate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This select first all individual player_IDs and uses them to get the numbers

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `game_match` (
>   `ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'The unique ID of the match,',
>   `ACCOUNT_ONE_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign key for Player 1.',
>   `ACCOUNT_TWO_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign key for Player 2.',
>   `WINNER_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign key for which of the two players won.',
>   INDEX(ACCOUNT_ONE_ID, ACCOUNT_TWO_ID, WINNER_ID) ,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE
> );
>
> INSERT INTO game_match
>   (ACCOUNT_ONE_ID, ACCOUNT_TWO_ID, WINNER_ID)
> VALUES
>   (0, 1, 0),
>     (1, 2, 2),
>     (1, 2, 1),
>     (0, 1, 0),
>     (1, 0, 0),
>     (2, 1, 2),
>     (0, 2, 0),
>     (0, 1, 1);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> DISTINCT
> PlayerID,
> (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM game_match WHERE (ACCOUNT_ONE_ID = t1.PlayerID OR ACCOUNT_TWO_ID = t1.PlayerID) AND WINNER_ID =  t1.PlayerID) MATCHES_WON,
> (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM game_match WHERE (ACCOUNT_ONE_ID = t1.PlayerID OR ACCOUNT_TWO_ID = t1.PlayerID) AND WINNER_ID <> t1.PlayerID) MATCHES_LOST
> FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ACCOUNT_ONE_ID  AS PlayerID FROM game_match
> UNION
> SELECT DISTINCT ACCOUNT_TWO_ID FROM game_match) t1
> ```

> ```
> PlayerID | MATCHES_WON | MATCHES_LOST
> -------: | ----------: | -----------:
>        0 |           4 |            1
>        1 |           2 |            5
>        2 |           2 |            2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=847939d9da179851cfed4e19b306d68b)*

Comment: Thank you so much! That is a bit more involved than I'd have thought, but not so bad! I really need to polish my SQL skills back up again after doing mostly backend code for so long :D

Comment: Mysql 8 and Maradb 10.2 have window functions, that you must look at, they make the life in combination with cTE easier

Comment: Will try and keep that in mind. Thanks for the tip.